# Cant connect to SSH outside port Cisco ASA 5506

Tags: ssh, cisco, cisco-asa, wide-area-network

Im configuring an ASA for my home and i got SSH working for internal networks but when trying to configure it for outside, it cant connect.

The steps i took to setup the ASA was to allow the internal networks first:

`asa(config)# ssh 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 inside`

`asa(config)# ssh 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.224 wireless`

`asa(config)# ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 outside`

Then created the `RSA` key:

`asa(config)# crypto key generate rsa modulus 2048`

Then added an ACL to allow the connection:

`asa(config)# access-list SSH extended permit tcp any any eq ssh`

This is what i had and made more changes as i went on troubleshooting this issue. I read in other answers that i should use an 1024 RSA key instead of 2048, changed it and it still does not connect. Before changing it, it was suggested to remove the other RSA keys with `asa(config)# crypto key zeroize rsa` and then added a new 1024 RSA but still no connection. I have also changed around with the ACL's and even changed to `ssh key-exchange group dh-group14-sha1`. I also turned off `asa(config)# no ssh stricthostkeycheck` and still no connection.

aaa is also set to `asa(config)# aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL` so as mentioned, it works inside but not for outside.

I also enabled `asa(config)# debug ssh 127` as suggested in another question and tried connecting to the ASA but i dont seem to get any errors or activity when attempting to connect from outside but from inside it shows activity.

Not sure where to go from here. Any help appreciated. Will keep troubleshooting...

Comment: Can you post a full configuration with your passwords scrubbed?

Comment: Are you testing this over the Internet or with an SSH client directly connected to the outside interface? Does the ASA have internet connectivity? Does the outside interface have a public IP address? Does it have a default route?

Comment: sorry for late reply. The ASA is configured with DHCP since its a resident account with Spectrum. I am using Putty to connect to my home IP so yes, testing over internet